# How to iterate an object from the npm package "csvtojson"

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a problem converting my csv to json with the npm package "csvtojson". First, I converted it into an ascii character set, then I used the conversion to utf16 offered by the package, but now they appear to me as "[object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object], [object Object] "

I tried to iterate the object, but without success. I need your help. Then I leave an image of the csv.

[image]

```
const csvFilePath='./download/negocio.csv'
const csv=require('csvtojson');

app.get('/api', async(req, res) => {
  var jsonArray=await csv().fromFile(csvFilePath);
  jsonArray =  jsonArray.toString('utf16');

  res.json(jsonArray);

});
```

Comment: Have you read [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csvtojson#from-csv-file-to-json-array)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this first

```
const utils = require('../helper/util');

const path = './download/negocio.csv';

app.get('/api', async (req, res) => {
  const result = await utils.csvToJson(path);
  return res.status(200).json(res);
});
```

**utils.js**

```
const csv = require('csvtojson');

const utils = {};

utils.csvToJson = async (path) => {
  try {
    const jsonArray = await csv().fromFile(path);
    return jsonArray;
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};

module.exports = utils;
```

> **Note** keeps eyes on the path. The path `./downloads/..` can be different for one file to another file.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I still get the following error: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON

Comment: Modify by this: return res.status (200) .json (result); but now I get everything in ascii: [{"��K \ u0000e \ u0000y \ u0000w \ u0000o \ u0000r \ u0000d \ u0000 \ u0000S \ u0000t \ u0000a "},

Comment: Try with another csv